# variant & price load in shopify

Tags: ajax, shopify, shopify-activemerchant

Product price for default variant is working.When i change variant "Inc VAT" is not changing automatically.
I want to change product price automatically, when i will change variant of a product. See the store-
https://woodies-timber.myshopify.com/products/bendi-ply-long-grain

```
<div class="price dvt-vat">
                  {%- include 'limited-offer' -%}
                  <div id="price">
                    {%- if product.available -%}
                    <span class="price-new money">{{current_variant.price | money}}</span>
                    {%- if current_variant.compare_at_price > current_variant.price -%}
                    <span class="price-old money">{{current_variant.compare_at_price | money}}</span>
                    {%- endif -%}
                    {%- else -%}
                    <span class="price-old">{{'products.product.sold_out' | t}}</span>
                    {%- endif -%}
                  </div>
                  <span class="exl-vat">Exl VAT</span>

                    {% assign dvt_price = current_variant.price  %}
                    {% assign dvt_price_prat = current_variant.price | times :20 | divided_by :100 | plus: current_variant.price | money %}
                    <br>
                    <span class="price-new money dvt_price_totlal">{{ dvt_price_prat }}</span>
                    <span class="exl-vat">Inc VAT</span>


                </div>
```

Comment: Is the problem that changing the selected variant isn't updating the display?  If so, you'll want to find the function that runs when variants change (often called `selectCallback`, especially on older themes) and put the update code that you want to run in there.

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/43826194/319741 shows how to handle older templates without selectCallback - it does stock updates, but price updates will be similar.